# Setting Parse PFGeopoints on a map only viewable for current user

Tags: parse-platform, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have an array of PFGeopoints which I query from parses back end database, and I then annotate them points onto a MapView. I now a feature in my app where you can turn yourself off so nobody can see where you are, but the current user can still see other people.

I have thought about setting the current location to O,O but this will not allow the current user to view anybody else then.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your question is?

Comment: What more do you need to know? I want to be able to see other people around me on a map view, but them not see me. This is in IOS by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to have a column in the database named `visible`. You should only query for users that have it set as true. When you don't want a user to be seen, set his `visible` column to false.